# How to get both Microphone and Camera permissions with webview

Tags: android-studio, webview

I am getting error "Either grant() or deny() has been already called" when I am trying to access a page in WebView that requires both Microphone and Camera access.

That's my on onPermissionRequest but for some reason if both of them are requested in the same time the app crashes but with only one request seems to work fine.

```
           override fun onPermissionRequest(permissionRequest: PermissionRequest?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onJSPermissionRequest")

            val mPermissionRequest: PermissionRequest? = permissionRequest

            for (request in permissionRequest?.resources!!){
                if (request == PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE){
                    val alertDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                            .setTitle("Allow Permission to Camera access!")
                            .setPositiveButton("Allow") { dialog, which ->
                                dialog.dismiss()
                                mPermissionRequest?.grant(arrayOf(PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE))
                            }
                            .setNegativeButton("Deny") { dialog, which ->
                                dialog.dismiss()
                                mPermissionRequest?.deny()
                            }
                    val alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create()
                    alertDialog.show()
                }
                if(request == PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_AUDIO_CAPTURE){
                    val alertDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                            .setTitle("Allow Permission to Microphone access!")
                            .setPositiveButton("Allow") { dialog, which ->
                                dialog.dismiss()
                                mPermissionRequest?.grant(arrayOf(PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_AUDIO_CAPTURE))
                            }
                            .setNegativeButton("Deny") { dialog, which ->
                                dialog.dismiss()
                                mPermissionRequest?.deny()
                            }
                    val alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create()
                    alertDialog.show()
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onPermissionRequestCanceled(request: PermissionRequest?) {
            super.onPermissionRequestCanceled(request)
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

I know the issue is because I asking for grant twice (removing the grant command in one of the cases solves the crash but now giving permissions) but the resources are different for both requests..